# QBSDK Add Customer Job

Tags: quickbooks

How do you add a job to an existing customer. I have tried both CustomerAddRq and CustomerModRq and neither works.  My client wants to create a new job for each customer contract and track invoices and bills by job.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Answered below. If you continue to have trouble, POST THE QBXML that you're sending and having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

To add a job, you call `CustomerAdd` and specify the `ParentRef` of the parent customer.

For example:

```
<CustomerAddRq>
  <CustomerAdd>
    <Name>Child Customer Name</Name>
    <ParentRef>
      <FullName>Parent Customer Name</FullName>
    </ParentRef>
    <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
    <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
    <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
    <Email>support@consolibyte.com</Email>
  </CustomerAdd>
</CustomerAddRq>
```

Here's a few additional examples:

- [qbXML for adding a job](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Adding_a_Customer_with_a_parent_%28adding_a_Job%29)
- [other qbXML examples](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests)